# Why is this simple python class not working?

Tags: python, class, list

I'm trying to make a class that will get a list of numbers then print them out when I need. I need to be able to make 2 objects from the class to get two different lists. Here's what I have so far

```
class getlist:   
    def newlist(self,*number):
        lst=[]
        self.number=number
        lst.append(number)

    def printlist(self):
        return lst
```

Sorry I'm not very clear, I'm a bit new to oop, can you please help me cos I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Indentation is significant in Python, so this example will never run. Please fix it so we can see what you're trying to do.

Comment: why do you need objects here, lists are not enough for you?

Comment: @SilentGhost - while a valid point in general, Michael is probably making a toy program as a learning exercise.

Answer (score 7):

In Python, when you are writing methods inside an object, you need to prefix all references to variables belonging to that object with self. - like so:

```
class getlist:   
    def newlist(self,*number):
        self.lst=[]
        self.lst += number #I changed this to add all args to the list

    def printlist(self):
        return self.lst
```

The code you had before was creating and modifying a local variable called lst, so it would appear to "disappear" between calls.

Also, it is usual to make a constructor, which has the special name `__init__` :

```
class getlist:   
    #Init constructor
    def __init__(self,*number):
        self.lst=[]
        self.lst += number #I changed this to add all args to the list

    def printlist(self):
        return self.lst
```

Finally, use like so

```
>>> newlist=getlist(1,2,3, [4,5])
>>> newlist.printlist()
[1, 2, 3, [4,5]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use "self.lst" instead of "lst". Without the "self", it's just internal variable to current method.

Comment: Thats brilliant, that seems to have sorted it, Thanks for the help everyone!